# jQuery mobile ajax login form authentication

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, jquery-mobile

I know i already asked simillar question, but now when I work with jQuery Mobile I can't figure it out. So I have this form:

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="login_page">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>****</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <form id="login_form" method="POST" data-ajax="false">
            <label for="basic">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="username" value=""/>
            <label for="basic">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value=""/>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" id="login" name="login"/>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <div data-role="navbar"></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

And I need to submit Username and Password to php script, where php replies and send "success" or "failed". Here is php:

```
<?php
session_start();

$username = $_POST["name"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

include('mysql_connection.php');
mysql_select_db("jzperson_imesUsers", $con);

$res1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM temp_login WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
$count=mysql_num_rows($res1);

if($count==1){
    echo "success";
}else{
    echo "failed";
}
?>
```

And to do all this I want to use this script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("form").submit(function(){
            $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();

            $.ajax({
                url: "http://imes.jzpersonal.com/login_control.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                jsonp: "jsoncallback",
                data: $("form#login_form").serialize(),
                success: function( response ){
                    $.mobile.changePage( "http://imes.jzpersonal.com/user_panel.html");
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

But I can't make it work, I know I must have mistakes in there, I just can't find them, or better way to do it. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: your php script suffers from SQL injection...

Comment: The whole aproach of ajax authentication doesn't have anything to with security. What if someone calls http://imes.jzpersonal.com/user_panel.html directly? You need authentication there!

Comment: So how else I can authenticate without making my .html file .php files?

Comment: Well, the best would be to make it a .php file. But if you cannot, you should create a .php file that performs authentication and then uses server-side includes (that means the require_once keyword) to display the .html file. The .html file must not be accessable directly. If that is not possible for you either, you have to drop form authentication in favor to basic authentication: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_auth_basic.html

Comment: looking for more detailed answer to your post, since jsonp will not support POST how did you accomplish this - I see your php still has `$username = $_POST["name"];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have few mistakes.

I. JSONP only allows type: "GET" but you can remove it altogether.

This is a working example of JSONP $.ajax call:

```
   $.ajax({url: server_url,
        data: save_data,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: 'successCallback',
        async: true,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(true);
        },
        complete: function() {
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
        },
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
        },
        error: function (request,error) {
            alert(error);
        }, 
       successCallback:function(){

        }
    });
```

II. Now the main thing, because you are using JSON/JSONP you cant just use echo "SOME_STRING" in PHP. First you must use a json_encode() function to format correctly your result data and the you need to wrap it in your jsonpCallback function:

```
echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . "{'some' : 'example'}" . ')';
```

or:

```
echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . ###your_serialized_json_output### . ')';
```

III. And finally you need to modify your server so it can handle JSONP calls.

Here you will find more about it:

http://www.geekality.net/2010/06/27/php-how-to-easily-provide-json-and-jsonp/

Comment: You obviously know what are you talking about. If I need to keep my files .html, so I won't put php scripts to authenticate into them, how else I can authenticate? Is there a way to authenticate without changing my files into .php? To store login information in cookie for certain amount of time, and authenticate through JS or jQuery?

Comment: You still need to use a php to authenticate the user. Point of my answer is you need a proper php echo output so client side can receive a real msg. If you need more info how to implement this solution please leave an another comment.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's usually a good idea to do as much work as you can on the client side, authentication should be done server side. Your `user_panel` script should check for authentication.

Secondly, you should protect your SQL request from injection by using `mysql_real_escape_string`. Your code should be :

```php
$res1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM temp_login 
                     WHERE   username='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'])."' 
                     AND password='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password'])."'");
```